# Reading IPTC properties on QuickTime files with MetadataExtractor in C#?

Tags: c#, metadata-extractor

I'm successfully using the MetadataExtractor library in C# to read EXIF and IPTC information out of JPEG files.

In Windows Explorer and Lightroom I can set similar values on .mp4 files (like headline and description), and see those values reflected in Windows Explorer and Lightroom. I can't see them with MetadataExtractor, however.

Is there a way to access them? The only metadata directories I'm getting back are File Type, Movie Header, Track Header, and File.

Thanks!

Comment: The master branch of the project currently has unreleased improvements to video file processing. Could you test against the code from master please?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I grabbed from master and tried it out but am still not seeing the IPTC/EXIF headers.

Comment: Is there any way you could get an file that contains the metadata you're after to me? Perhaps you can open a GitHub issue and attach a zip.

Comment: Logged, thanks. If you need any other details feel free to ping me over on github.